# Різниця між словами “контент” та “вміст”

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Вітаю, шановне панство!

Виникло таке запитання: чи критичною є різниця між словами "контент" та "вміст" в контексті наповнення якого-небуть веб сайту (наприклад: "дорослий контент" чи "вміст для дорослих")?

Вікі каже, що контент і вміст - це синоніми:

> Інформаці́йне напо́внення са́йту (англ. content, вміст)  — це інформація чи досвід, який направлений на кінцевих користувачів чи аудиторію., яку розробник складає самостійно або копіює з дотриманням чинного законодавства.[1]

СУМ-11 "знає" лише про "вміст":

> ВМІСТ (УМІСТ), у, чол. 
>   1. Те, що є, міститься в чому-небудь. *Коли сідав до стола, то цікавився вмістом чарок, стаканів і стопочок переважно* (Іван Сенченко, Опов., 1959, 65). 
>   2. Наявність якої-небудь речовини в складі чого-небудь. *Внаслідок вмісту кофеїну, чай має тонізуючі властивості* (Українські страви, 1957, 284); 
>   //  Кількість якоїсь речовини в складі чого-небудь...

Чи є принципова різниця між цими двома словами?
Яке зі слів краще використовувати у тексті або повсякденному спілкуванні для надання йому більшої відповідності? На перший погляд здається, що вони рівноцінні, але, як на мене, "контент" більш схильний до IT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

З СУМ-20

> **[ВМІСТ (УМІ́СТ)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15274&page=503)** у, ч. **1.** Те, що є, міститься в чому-небудь.  *Коли сідав до стола, то цікавився вмістом чарок, стаканів і стопочок переважно* (І. Сенченко); *“Хай їй там добре ведеться”, – зітхнув я, оновлюючи вміст наших келихів молодим соаве [італійським білим вином]* (Ю. Андрухович)  **2.** Наявність якоїсь речовини у складі чого-небудь.
> **//** Кількість якоїсь речовини у складі чого-небудь.
>
> **[КОНТЕ́НТ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=193469&page=1381)** у, ч., інформ. Зміст будь-якого видання, телепередачі і т. ін. // Зміст, інформаційне наповнення сайту.
> *Контент охороняється законом про авторське право, оскільки він є продуктом інтелектуальної праці й має своїх авторів і власників* (з
> мови документів); *Окрім якості контенту, одним із важливих критеріїв
> є його доступність* (із журн.).

Слова мають абсолютно різне значення та не можуть бути синонімами. На мою думку, слід розділити використання даних слів (не використовувати, як взаємозамінні). ***"Вміст"*** має більш ширше значення, отже, більш широкий спект використання. ***"Контент"*** слід використовувати, коли говоримо про наповнення сайту, телепередачі (ІТ сфера).